# How can I run MAME on an iMac G4 (PowerPC)

Tags: powerpc

I'd like to install and run MAME binaries on an iMac G4 (PowerPC), and information on this seems to be very limited. [Official MAME pages](http://wiki.mamedev.org/index.php/SDL_Supported_Platforms) link to two pages related to Power PC Macs.

1. [Apple Macintosh OS X PowerPC](https://mirrors.xmission.com/mame/mac/sdlmame/) leads to a long list of which [this one](https://mirrors.xmission.com/mame/mac/sdlmame/mame0165-32bit.zip) seems to be the newest 32 bit version. However, `./mame` says "Can't execute file". Evidently because it's an Intel file!
2. [Apple Macintosh OS X PowerPC (10.5)](https://www.mediafire.com/folder/07r0cvcq1i39g/OSX_PPC_10.5_%28SDL2%29) links to another list of versions which I haven't tried yet (because of hardware problems). And my machine has 10.4, so maybe that won't work...?

Is anyone out there successfully running MAME binaries on a PowerPC Mac, that can provide working instructions for how to set this up? Along with any depencies or configuration required.

Comment: The `mame` in this zip identifies as `Mach-O executable i386`, no wonder it doesn't work for you.

Comment: The 2nd sentence on their wiki that you linked to says "Technical support for MAME on non-Windows platforms and for MESS on all platforms is available on the bannister.org forums."

Comment: http://forums.bannister.org//ubbthreads.php?ubb=postlist&Board=8&page=1

Comment: Maybe posting a question on the forum (where the MAME experts seem to hang out) regarding availability of a PPC version will get an answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can get PPC version 0.103 at [MacMAME](http://www.macmame.org/downloads.html)

You'll need a ROM set of the same vintage, so search for "MAME 0.106 reference set" or similar.

You want either a specific PPC build or a Universal build. All builds labelled 32bit or 64bit are Intel only. sdlmame0140-universal would also work but compared to MacMAME it's more difficult to configure, which also applies to those in your 2nd link.

Finally, I would like to recommend you play SEGA's 1984 classic [Flicky](http://www.mobygames.com/game/arcade/flicky).

Have fun!

Comment: @forthrin google hash 3c6227e86fd5ecbd7b9b661e2c4af86640dd5619

Comment: @forthrin you're talking about computers 13 or more years old, and software that has likely not been touched for a similar amount of time. This is as good as it gets!

Comment: @forthrin you want either a specific PPC build or a Universal build. All builds labelled 32bit or 64bit are Intel. sdlmame0140-universal would also work but compared to MacMAME it's more difficult to configure, which also applies to those in your 2nd link.

Comment: How did you get on @forthrin?

Comment: Start a new question about Linux. But as for any old version of MAME it will only support the snapshot of games that were current when it was released. Since then new games will have been added, but all the well let known games ones it will probably have. You'll have to use a set of roms from the same era.

Comment: You might be better of going down this road: https://retropie.org.uk/forum/topic/7116/pi-inside-an-emac-g3

Comment: Also see https://archive.org/details/MAME0.106-Reference-Set-ROMs-CHDs-Samples

Comment: But accounts are free, just a small barrier to reduce downloads of popular files